# Transforming Spark Dataframe Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Spark dataframes. I have a categorical variable in my dataframe with many levels. I am attempting a simple transformation of this variable - Only pick the top few levels which has greater than n observations (say,1000). Club all other levels into an "Others" category.

I am fairly new to Spark, so I have been struggling to implement this. This is what I have been able to achieve so far:

```
# Extract all levels having > 1000 observations (df is the dataframe name) 
val levels_count = df.groupBy("Col_name").count.filter("count >10000").sort(desc("count"))

# Extract the level names
val level_names = level_count.select("Col_name").rdd.map(x => x(0)).collect
```

This gives me an Array which has the level names that I would like to retain. Next, I should define the transformation function which can be applied to the column. This is where I am getting stuck. I believe we need to create a User defined function. This is what I tried:

```
# Define UDF
val var_transform = udf((x: String) => {
    if (level_names contains x) x
    else "others"
 })

# Apply UDF to the column
val df_new = df.withColumn("Var_new", var_transform($"Col_name"))
```

However, when I try  `df_new.show`  it throws a "Task not serializable" exception. What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: let me know the output of level_count.select("Col_name").rdd.map(x => x(0)).collect

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu An array of values which has the levels that I would wish to retain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that would be, in my opinion, better for such a simple transformation: stick to the DataFrame API and trust catalyst and Tungsten to be optimised (e.g. making a broadcast join):

```
val levels_count = df
  .groupBy($"Col_name".as("new_col_name"))
  .count
  .filter("count >10000")

val df_new = df
  .join(levels_count,$"Col_name"===$"new_col_name", joinType="leftOuter")
  .drop("Col_name")
  .withColumn("new_col_name",coalesce($"new_col_name", lit("other")))
```

Comment: This gives me a type mismatch error....found   : String("other")
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: Ha, sorry, I wrote it in the dark. In this case you have the org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit function that create a column from a literal.

Comment: @Wilmerton..Thank you! this works..also just for my understanding, any idea what was wrong with my code? I can get the UDF to work for other cases, so I believe the issue I am facing is related to comparing the column values against a series of values..I come from R, where I would have used a %in% for this comparison..what;s the best way to do this in Spark dataframes?

Comment: A serialisation error occurs when a part of your logic cannot be serialized to be shipped to executors. Here you are doing something dangerous by creating a Scala collection (on your driver), then that you use it in a UDF without storing it in a broadcast variable. But I don't know enough to tell you exactly in which case it cannot be serialised (sometimes in works, for instance if you create a simple hard-coded map). But it is anyway not good practice. Read a bit about spark internals and variable broadcasting (google is your friend).

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you last question... You can use the [`isin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isin(list:Any*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) method: `df.select($"col".isin(list:_*))` .   Is your problem solved?